# How to find the port number of jvm which is running in ubuntu

Tags: jvm

How can I know the debug port number of jvm (Java Virtual Machine) in Linux?

Comment: Are you talking about the Java Virtual Machine (jvm)? If yes, which port are you looking for? The debug port?

Comment: Yes Java Virtual Machine. Yes the debug port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the debug port is not enabled by default.  You have to enable it via the -Xdebug parameter.  Here is an example how to start java with enabled debugging and port 8000 as debug port:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n ...
```

Comment: Yes this was my solution:   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

Answer (score 1):

As per Stefan Endrullis suggestion, This was my solution:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```